# VS2010 WPF DataGrid Sorts Improperly

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid

I am using a WPF DataGrid with procedurally (C#, VS 2010) generated, bound columns, and the DataGrid will not sort data correctly.

CanUserSortColumns is set to true.
SortMemberPath is set to the same property as the text displayed in the grid.

Regardless of which column the user sorts, and despite the sort icon being displayed over the appropriate column, the DataGrid merely alternates the sort order of the first column.

```
column.Header = departmentColumn.ColumnHeader;
column.Width = departmentColumn.ColumnWidth;
column.Binding = new Binding("Cells[" + departmentColumn.Ordinal.ToString() + "]");
column.SortMemberPath = "DisplayString";
```

I have no problems with any other data being displayed or used incorrectly by the DataGrid, so I am stumped.  Why would the sort only consider text in the first column, when everything else binds to data from the appropriate column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a couple hours on this today, I found the answer myself almost immediately after I posted the question.

I had to change:

```
column.SortMemberPath = "DisplayString";
```

To:

```
column.SortMemberPath = "Cells[" + departmentColumn.Ordinal.ToString() + "].DisplayString";
```

I guess SortMemberPath does not always automatically bind to the current data item.

My thanks to anyone who already started working on this.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I sort the datagrid, maybe it will help

```
Dim cv As ICollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dgMyDataGrid.ItemsSource)
cv.SortDescriptions.Clear()
cv.SortDescriptions.Add(New SortDescription("iOrderNum", ListSortDirection.Ascending))
cv.Refresh()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am not sure if this would address my problem.  I was trying to get the DataGrid to utilize its built-in sorting features, so users could click on column headers in order to sort.  If I am wrong in assuming this does not do that, I apologize.  Regardless, I should have been more specific.

Comment: This actually helped me to fix sorting on a periodically refreshed DataGrid, when i wanted it to retain previously applied sorting.

Answer (score 0):

According to the DataGridColumn.SortMemberPath Property page at MSDN, the `SortMemberPath` property sets

> The path of the data-item member to sort by

This would lead me to believe that you should *not* set this property *unless* you only want to sort by the one column that you set it to.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, Sheridan.  This is an instance-specific field, meaning you set it once for each column.  Regardless, I solved the problem by including the full path, rather than assuming the DataGrid would start with the currently bound data item.